# running sqlite from php5-sqlite install

Tags: apt, php, database, sqlite

I have installed php5 and sqlite3 by using:

`sudo apt-get install -y php5 php5-sqlite unzip`

But when I run `sqlite` (or `sqlite3`) in the terminal, it says that I need to install it using `apt-get`.

I would like to dump my database, but I can't run sqlite to get at it.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`php5-sqlite` only installs the SQlite plugin for `php5`.  `sqlite` and `sqlite3` are both ***separate*** programs, and they aren't `php5` plugins.

Run `sudo apt-get install sqlite sqlite3` to install both of the command-line SQlite client utilities.  The `php5` plugins don't need the binaries, so they're not actually installed by your `apt-get` command you say you ran.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that's very helpful - so how would you suggest dumping a sqlite database that was created by PHP5-sqlite3? Should I install sqlite separately, load it in, and then dump it?

Comment: @YoungPadawan That's about your only option.  Note that most php5 applications don't use SQLite they use a real database, so using a real database system in the future is a requirement.